# & Turns into &amp; in metadata

Tags: html, view-source

I have a simple problem regarding &amp. I decided to upload a simple csv file just to insert meta title and meta description.

It uploaded sucessfully but when i use the view source i can see this &

```html
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title> Jack &amp; Jill </title>
</head>
```

My question is how do i change & into & ?

I tried manually inputting Jack & Jill. But still when i check the
view souce. It still transforms into a &

Hope you can help me.

Comment: This is completely correct way of encoding &. Why do you want to break it? And uploaded csv where? Why is it html suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do i change `&amp;` into & ?

I wouldn't, if I were you. `&amp;` is just the HTML-encoded (and XML-encoded) form of `&`. The browser will display it as `&`.

I don't know offhand whether an `&` followed by a space is even valid in strict XML (I know this is HTML, not XML) but it's reasonable to *always* escape it, so that you don't need to worry about situations like:

```
I love Jack&Jill; they're great
```

... where `Jill` would be seen as an entity reference without any escaping.

Comment: Hi is there any way the view source would not convert & into &amp;? or is it a bad practice to force it to change into &. thanks

Comment: @shadowbudz: No. When you use "view source" you're viewing the raw HTML. You shouldn't *expect* that to be "unescaped"...